Save (backup) App-specific keyboard shortcuts in MacOS
I have created quite a lot of App-specific shortcuts through the 'Keyboard Shortcut' in System Settings in MacOS. Wondering if I could port it to a new machine or save those key-bindings somehow? For example,

when setting up a new machine
when Time Machine backUps are unavailable (not sure if it saves those key bindings)


Those will transfer over to a new Mac if you use Apple's Migration Assistant or a full backup from CCC or SuperDuper. But, of course, that means that you are duplicating one Mac to another....

It seems that the keyboard shortcut settings are stored in the following files:
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist 
~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist

There may be more stashed away somewhere else, but that should be most of it.
